# How to solve this generalization of binary search?

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request

Let $f:\{1,\ldots,n\}$ be a monotonically non-decreasing function.

Consider, for some unknown threshold $1\le T\le n$, a threshold function 
$$g(x)= \begin{cases}
0&\text{x<T}\\
1&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Our goal is to find $T$ while minimizing the worst case cost, where computing $g(x)$ for any $x\in\{1,\ldots n\}$ has a cost of $f(x)$. 
We assume that $f$ is known.

There are two straightforward approaches for this: a linear scan and a binary search.

It's not hard to see that each of them is good for different scenarios -- a linear scan works fine for $f(x)=2^{x}$ while a binary search is optimal for $f(x)=1$.

Since $f(n/2)$ may be much larger than $f(T)$, another approach is to use doubling and then binary search. The cost of this is bounded by $O(f(2T)\log T)$. This can be modified to 
$$O(\epsilon^{-1} f(T)\log T +  f(T(1+\epsilon))\log (T\epsilon))$$ 
by doing the doubling using a $(1+\epsilon)$ factor.

> If this problem is known, What is the name of this problem?
>
> What is the optimal strategy here?

---

Obviously, it is possible to exhaustively compute the correct strategy. Can we compute it (or an approximation of it) faster? Is it possible to give an analytical formula for it?

I am aware that the problem is somewhat vague. Mainly, I am wondering if it is possible to analytically find an optimal solution (using the $f(i)$ values) and if not, if it is possible to compute a reasonable strategy given $f$ as an input.
You may also assume additional reasonable properties on $f$.

Answer (score 3):

The optimal strategy can be found through dynamic programming in $O(n^3)$ time.  Let $A[i,j]$ denote the worst-case cost of the optimal strategy when $T$ is already known to be in $\{i,i+1,\dots,j\}$.  Then we have the recursive relation

$$A[i,k] = \min \{f(j) + \max(A[i,j], A[j+1,k]) : j=i,i+1,\dots,k-1\},$$

with the base case $A[i,i] = 0$.  You can use dynamic programming to fill out this array.  The assumption that $f$ is non-decreasing is not needed; this works whenever $f$ is any non-negative function.

Comment: It might be said that the $O(n^3)$ is a factor $O(n^2)$ for the number of entries in $A$ and a factor $O(n)$ to find the optimal $j$ in each step. Can the latter be found with binary search instead, in the $f$ is non-decreasing case, for a total runtime of $O(n^2\log n)$?

Comment: @AlbertHendriks, I don't immediately see how, but maybe you have some idea.  The challenge I see is that $f(j)$ is a non-decreasing function of $j$ but $A[j+1,k]$ is a non-increasing function of $j$, so $f(j)+A[j+1,k]$ might not be a monotonic function of $j$, and I'm not sure how to deal with that.